# Error in predicting Float values in kNN in python

Tags: python

I am new to this KNN I want to ask a simple question I have written a code in python of KNN. when I used fingerprints.csv that contains decimals number my code gives me an error. I assume that it doesn't predict float values. so I used another CSV that has similar data but no decimal value my code worked well.
what changes I should make so my code will be able to predict floats.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pickle
import glob
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

# training/validation set
train_set = pd.read_csv("1.csv")

# test set
test_set = pd.read_csv("testing data.csv")

X = train_set.iloc[:,0:3].values  #RSSI
Y = train_set.iloc[:,3:5].values  #X,Y (OUTCOME)


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#print(X_train.shape)
#print(X_test)
#print(Y_train.shape)
#print(Y_test)

sc = StandardScaler()                #feature scalin
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#print(Y_train)
aa =(X_train[:,0]+X_train[:,1]+X_train[:,2])/3
print(aa)

#import math
#print(math.sqrt(len(Y_test))) 
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, metric='euclidean')
classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(knn, n_jobs=-2)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Save the trained model as a pickle string.
saved_model = pickle.dumps (classifier)
  
# Load the pickled model
classifier_from_pickle = pickle.loads(saved_model)

# Use the loaded pickled model to make predictions
classifier_from_pickle.predict(X_test)


Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(Y_pred)

a = Y_test[:,0]   # actual labels
b = Y_pred[:,0]   # predicted labels
acc = len([a[i] for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] == b[i]]) / len(a)
a = Y_test[:,1]   # actual labels
b = Y_pred[:,1]   # predicted labels
accu = len([a[i] for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] == b[i]]) / len(a)
accuracy=acc+accu
print("Accuracy: ",accuracy)

#Model Validation on Validation.csv
X = test_set.iloc[:,0:3].values  #RSSI
#print(X)
X_test = sc.transform(X)
#print(X_test)
aa =(X_test[:,0]+X_test[:,1]+X_test[:,2])/3
print(aa)

# Use the loaded pickled model to make predictions on Validate Dataset
classifier_from_pickle.predict(X_test)


Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(Y_pred)
```

**the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/knnn code/knn2.py", line 53, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "C:\Users\92316\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multioutput.py", line 359, in fit
    super().fit(X, Y, sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\92316\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multioutput.py", line 156, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\92316\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'
```

thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Please create a [mre] and edit your question to include it.

Comment: It looks like your Y values (Y_train, Y_test) might be continuous. This will be a problem for classifiers where you seek labels for a finite, discrete set of values. Please check your data.

Comment: @ELinda. Yes my dataset consists of decimal number. What could be the possible solution then? Should i change the data set or is there anyother way to get rid of this error?

Comment: There should be a discrete set of values for Y, you can try changing those values